# Is it possible to bypass my old password-protected .7z archive which was saved by 7-Zip in late 2011?

Tags: windows-10, security, passwords, 7-zip

In November 2011, I created a .7z archive file that's about 870 megs, using 7-Zip. Apparently, I password-protected it without saving the password...

I highly doubt that it contains anything of value, but there is that nagging feeling at the back of my mind which says:

> You know that this is it. This is all those lost backups that you've cried over for so many years now. You made one final backup and secured it with a password before losing the physical media. You know it's true. You NEED to access that archive!

But the password is completely unknown. Most likely, it is some random string which can never be guessed manually, and it's definitely not a dictionary word.

Is there some convenient vulnerability in password-protected .7z archives saved by **7-zip 9.25 alpha** or below? That version is the last possible version I could have used according to: https://www.7-zip.org/history.txt

I do not remember if I used the latest alpha or the stable version as of that date. *Probably* the stable one.

Brute-forcing the password seems like a futile attempt, but maybe it's sensible? There is also the problem of me not trusting software made by others, and the many problems that typically arise when trying to run some old password crack script from GitHub which only works if you run Linux and a very specific setup. I run Windows 10.

I have read the 7-Zip manual but found no command-line or GUI feature which would allow me to dump various useful data about my archive, such as which encryption method was used and strength and all that stuff. Seems like you cannot know that before the password is entered, but I may be wrong about that.

And yes, I was stupid for not properly naming the file and especially for not writing down the password in a manner which would actually be preserved. I was *significantly* dumber 11 years ago...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139591/discussion-on-question-by-turi-is-it-possible-to-bypass-my-old-password-protecte).

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your 7z file into a zip file, then you can install a program called PassFab which can literally brute force its way through that annoying password.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).